# Trying to fit data into a 7 parameters quadra-exponential function

Tags: python, curve-fitting, data-fitting

Here are some data for time t and corresponding f(t) values.

`

```
 time_before = [0.075, 0.1, 0.125, 0.15, 0.175, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3, 0.35, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.8, 1, 1.5, 2, 3, 4.5, 6] #in min/10

 time_after = [np.exp(-z) for z in time_before]

 Cp_data = [2.148738, 24.88158, 61.81409, 82.55928, 79.09638, 79.45628, 28.19074, 18.6571, 16.04993, 14.16715, 11.87659, 9.680828, 7.948303, 8.233573, 7.285041, 6.576602, 6.100967, 5.581709, 5.389457]`
```

I'm trying to fit it into a function :

`

```
def Cp(x, A1, A2, A3, L1, L2, L3, L4):   
    if Cp.count!=-1 :
        Cp.count += 1
    L=[]
    if Cp.count > 1 :
         print(f"Iteration {Cp.count-1}: A1 = {A1}, A2 = {A2}, A3 = {A3},L1 = {L1}, L2 = {L2}, L3 = {L3}, L4= {L4}")
    for t in x:
         L.append(A1 * t**L1 + A2 * t**L2 + A3 * t**L3 - (A1+A2+A3)*t**L4)
    return L`
```

So that at the end, the Cp(t) function gives :

Cp(t) = A1 * exp(-L1*t) + A2 * exp(-L2t) + A3 * exp(-L3*t) - (A1+A2+A3)*exp(-L4*t)
`

The idea was to reduce the time (time_before has already been divided by 10) and to put, as a timeframe, exp(-t) (in the "time after" list) so that the function to fit is polynomial towards exp(-t), which increases accuracy I guess.

But the problem is that the curve_fit module on python is not working because "ValueError: The model function generated NaN values and the fit aborted! Please check your model function and/or set boundaries on parameters where applicable. In cases like this, using "nan_policy='omit'" will probably not work."

Can you help me on it to get a fitted function from the data?

Thanks!

PS : here's the full code

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import lmfit
from scipy.optimize import root


def Cp(x, A1,L1, A2,L2, A3,L3, L4):
    if Cp.count!=-1 :
        Cp.count += 1
    L=[]
    if Cp.count > 1 :
        print(f"Iteration {Cp.count-1}: A1 = {A1}, A2 = {A2}, A3 = {A3},L1 = {L1}, L2 = {L2}, L3 = {L3}, L4= {L4}")
    for t in x:
        L.append(A1 * np.exp(-t*L1) + A2 * np.exp(-t*L2) + A3 * np.exp(-t*L3) - (A1+A2+A3)*np.exp(-t*L4))
    return L


Cp.count = 0

time = np.array([0.075, 0.1, 0.125, 0.15, 0.175, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3, 0.35, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.8, 1, 1.5, 2, 3, 4.5, 6])
concentration = np.array([2.148738, 24.88158, 61.81409, 82.55928, 79.09638, 79.45628, 28.19074, 18.6571, 16.04993, 14.16715, 11.87659, 9.680828, 7.948303, 8.233573, 7.285041, 6.576602, 6.100967, 5.581709, 5.389457])

#guess parameters

popt, _ = curve_fit(Cp, time, concentration, bounds=((0,0, 0, 0,0, 0,0), (np.inf, np.inf,np.inf,np.inf, np.inf,np.inf, np.inf)),maxfev=100000, verbose = 0)
A1,L1, A2,L2, A3,L3, L4 = popt

Cp.count = -1

#LM algo with initial parameters
model = lmfit.Model(Cp, independent_vars=['x'])
fit_result = model.fit(concentration, x=time, A1=A1, A2=A2, A3=A3, L1=L1, L2=L2, L3=L3, L4=L4)
params_list = list(fit_result.params.values())
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sorry if this sounds pessimistic, but your model is the sum of 4 exponentially decaying functions. How would the fit know how to distinguish one exponential from another?   And yet you gave no initial values for any of the parameters.  Initial values are absolutely required.  You should complain to the authors of `curve_fit` that their function allows the user to not give initial values.   Finally, if you have not asked yourself why you need 4 exponentials, now is the time to do that.